# keras : Implementing a custom metric with logical operators

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to create a custom metric to evaluate a keras model. The evaluation consist in returning 1 if y_true and y_pred are both higher  or lower than a certain value (in my case 5), 0 otherwise. The following lambda expression is a demo stating what I want to achieve

```
lambda y_pred, y_true : 1 if y_true > 5  and y_pred > 5 or y_true < 5 and y_pred < 5 else 0
```

I've tried to implement it on a custom keras model doing the following:

```
def SAGR(y_true, y_pred):
   maj = K.greater([y_true, y_pred], 5)
   men = K.less([y_true, y_pred], 5)
   aremaj= K.all(maj)
   aremen = K.all(men)
   res = K.any([aremaj, aremen])

  return K.mean(K.cast(res,'float32'))
```

But the function always return 0.

The output of the last layer is linear with shape [None, 2]. Can anyone please explain me a way to implement the custom metric?

Thanks

Comment: added an answer. Let me know if that helps, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are checking `aremaj= K.all(maj)` you need to check it with `axis=0`. Same goes for `aremen` and `res`

```
def SAGR(y_true, y_pred):
    maj = K.greater([y_true, y_pred], 5)
    men = K.less([y_true, y_pred], 5)
    aremaj= K.all(maj, axis=0)
    aremen = K.all(men, axis=0)
    res = K.any([aremaj, aremen], axis=0)
    res_final = K.mean(K.cast(res,'float32'))
    print(K.eval(res_final))
    return res_final
```

Explanation:

```
K.eval(maj) # Looks like this
[[False False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False]]

K.eval(K.all(maj)) # evaluates to 1 value:
False

print(K.eval(K.all(maj, axis=0)))
# What we actually want is a comparison at axis 0 level.
[False False  True False]
```

Working code: [Link](https://pastebin.com/Uam0kWtL)

PS: you can also use more detailed variable names as `aremaj` is not very descriptive and `SAGR` is upper case plus not descriptive.

Comment: FYI before this answer was posted I did solve using Tensorflow proprietary functions as following: `def newSAGR(y_true, y_pred):
    ma = tf.logical_and(K.greater(y_pred, 5),K.greater(y_true, 5))
    me = tf.logical_and(K.less(y_pred, 5),K.less(y_true, 5))
    return K.mean(tf.logical_or(ma, me))`